# React Native Expo publish to Android

Tags: react-native

I built a test application using react native. I'm trying to publish it following this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

However, my project does not have folder `android`. How can I create this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *React-native*, there are two  method to create Singed APK File

**[First you should know](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)**
it's best to create apps using react-native init rather than expo as React-Native-Cli gives you local project for both ios and android,you can test and debug the code locally and also use the tool to publish applications 
- If you create the project by using this command -

```
react-native init Project_Name
```

Then follow this [method](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html).

**BUT IN YOUR CASE**

you're using expo and also expo-cli! that's good! but when i use expo i usually like to go with expo XDE which has single version to publish,render or debug with it's own console in the bottom and that'll help you upload your code to **expo server** where you can ask them to render app for iOS or android and they will return you a link which will download the APK or the ipa file for android or iOS respectively

Here is the **[documentation link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps)** which'll explain you each step one by one and do keep an eye on the notes and TODOs while following the step (in your scenario) 
- If you use expo,for create React-native  project

then follow this [method generate the singed](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps) APK file for Android - Expo